# How to encrypt a partition multiple times?

Tags: security, encryption, disk-encryption

Is it possible to use cryptsetup only to encrypt a partition multiple times?

If not, what would you suggest to use to encrypt a partition say, 3 times in the most reliable way?

Comment: You could nest the encrypted filesystems by encrypting one of them, putting a large file on it, mapping it on loopback, putting an encrypted filesystem onto that, then repeat the process for the third layer of encryption. I don't know what that would really gain you versus just picking decent encryption to begin with, but there you go.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? Multiply encrypting won't add any security, but it will be costly computationally.

Comment: If you want to heat up the CPU and reduce security, there are simpler ways to do it. [Encrypting twice does not improve security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/is-multiple-encryption-a-good-idea).